# Expected unique0-if behavior inside a for loop

Tags: system-verilog

I am creating a parameterized module to direct register traffic to multiple targets. The parameters are the number of targets and the address ranges that each target responds to. I have coded this as an `if` inside of a `for` loop with default values set before the loop to handle the case where no address matches. I would like to use `unique0` to clarify that the ranges cannot overlap so this will not be implemented a a priority mux:

```
always_comb begin
  valid_addr = 1'b0;
  active_target  = '0;
  target_addr = '1;
  for(int i = 0; i<NUM_TARGETS; i++) begin
     unique0 if((addr >= START_ADDR[i]) && (paddr < (START_ADDR[i] + ADDR_SPAN[i]))) begin
        valid_addr = 1'b1;
        active_target = i;
        target_addr = addr - START_ADDR[i];
     end
  end
end
```

The question is: will this `unique0` do what I want? I am hoping that this is equivalent to the unrolled loop implemented as something like:

```
unique0 if ((addr >= START_ADDR[0]) && (paddr < (START_ADDR[0] + ADDR_SPAN[0]))) begin
  valid_addr = 1'b1;
  active_target = 0;
  target_addr = addr - START_ADDR[0];
end
else if  ((addr >= START_ADDR[1]) && (paddr < (START_ADDR[1] + ADDR_SPAN[1]))) begin
  valid_addr = 1'b1;
  active_target = 1;
  target_addr = addr - START_ADDR[1];
end
else begin
  valid_addr = 1'b0;
  active_target = '0;
  target_addr = '1;
end
```

I already have a problem since this will not compile with `unique0` but will compile with `unique` so that either answers my question or my simulator just doesn't like it for some reason:

```
unique0 if((addr >= START_ADDR[i]) && (addr < (START_ADDR[i] + ADDR_SPAN[i]))) begin
         |
expecting an '=' or '<=' sign in an assignment [9.2(IEEE)].
```

Comment: I now see that this is an academic exercise for me since I just looked at my synthesis tool docs and it explicitly does not support `unique0 if`. I will create a new question looking for better ideas on how to implement the logic I want.

Comment: there will be no 'else' in the unrolled version. Just two sequential uniqu0 if statements.

Comment: also, unique0 does absolutely nothing in your exercise.  It only makes sense with multiple if.. else if... conditions or with a case statement.

Answer (score 0):

in order to do what your unrolled statement implies and to make it synthesizable, you would need to use a match flag. Something like in the following:

```
logic match_flag; //<<<

always_comb begin
  match_flag = 1'b0; //<<<
  valid_addr = 1'b0;
  active_target  = '0;
  target_addr = '1;
  for(int i = 0; i<NUM_TARGETS; i++) begin
     if(!match_flag && (addr >= START_ADDR[i]) && (paddr < (START_ADDR[i] + ADDR_SPAN[i]))) begin
        valid_addr = 1'b1;
        active_target = i;
        target_addr = addr - START_ADDR[i];
        match_flag = 1'b1; //<<<
     end
  end
end
```

some synthesizers might support the *break* statement which could be used instead of the flag. Check documentation.